# How to make a Python object with an attribute that is a pdf file?

Tags: python, oop, pdf

I want to itemize all the paperwork for my job in a python file. So I want to make an object that includes the customer name, the job number, the location, and finally a pdf file of the actual paperwork.  How do I attach the pdf file as an attribute to a python object?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the data of the PDF-file as raw bytes and store them in a class attribute. Then if you want to save the stored bytes as a PDF-file again, you can just write the bytes to a file. Keep in mind that all the PDFs that you read in like that will be stored in memory (RAM). If you want to make a backup of the files, it would be better to copy or move them to a folder and just keep that path as an attribute. You can move or copy files with the shutil module.

If you want your program to be continuously running and always keep those objects alive, than you will run into problems with your memory quickly if you want to store let's say 10 GBs of PDF in that way.

"I want to itemize all the paperwork for my job in a python file."
This sentence leads me to believe that you misunderstand how this works. If you assign the contents of a PDF-Files to an attribute of an object, this will only be during the runtime of the script. As soon as you end the script, the object is gone. You can't "save it in a Python file". (Although you could encode your PDF as base64 and actually hardcode that string inside a python file if you really wanted but this is probably not your goal)

That being said, here is a possible way to do it:

```
class YourClass:
   
   def __init__(self, name, job_num, location, pdf_path):
      self.name = name
      self.job_num = job_num
      self.location = location
      self.pdf_data = self.get_pdf_data(pdf_path)

   def get_pdf_data(self, pdf_path):
      with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
         data = file.read()
      return data

   def save_pdf(self, pdf_path):
      with open(pdf_path, 'wb') as file:
         file.write(self.pdf_data)
```